# iOS Universal Links where the website contains "?" in the URL doesn't work

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to specify a specific part of the site to work with Universal links but there is a "?" in the part of the url that I want to specifiy. I think that maybe it's an issue because apple looks for nay 1 character when a '?' is specified. (iOS 9.3.5)

my association file looks like this

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [ 
    {
      "appID": "*redacted*",
      "paths": [
        "NOT /dontlookhere",
        "NOT /secretstuff",
        "NOT /secretstuff/*",
        "/?thingy=*"
      ]
    }
   ]
  }
}
```

The question mark before foobar is part of the url and would look something like this

```
https:www.foobar.com/?thingy=45
```

But this never seems to get matched, I have tried many different combinations to no avail. Does anyone have any insights as to why this isn't working?

Comment: Because that is part of the URL query string, universal links only look at the URL path.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. so is there no way that I can not show the link from the main page but still access this? since the query is right off of the main page?

Comment: No way that I know of without using a different path

Comment: I figured that might be the case, I'll see if we can extend the path. otherwise I guess the app could just redirect to safari if the query is invalid. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I think you could associate the base site, then decide whether you want to handle the link in application:openURL: or application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:?

Comment: Thank you, that's actually what I ended up doing, We have since moved everything to another folder though so that I can still display the app ad banner on the main index without conflict.